# Prevent duplicate ids from being added to session (array)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I got a session which adds ids to an array, the problem is every id gets added even if the id is already present. How can I prevent duplicate id's from being added to the array?

I figured I need to check for the id using in_array but I don't know exactly how to use it correctly.

I send the id of the product to my quote page using this link:

```
<p><a class="offertelink" href="offerte.php?product='.$productcr[0]['id'].'">Request a quote</a></p>
```

Then on that page I use the following code:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['product'])){
    $_SESSION['product'] = array();
}

// CHECK FIRST THAT $_GET['product'] IS SET BEFORE ADDING IT TO SESSION
if( isset($_GET['product'])){
    $_SESSION['product'][] = $_GET['product'];
}
$prods  = implode(",", $_SESSION['product']);
```

And finally load all the products with the ids that are inside the array:

```
if(count($_SESSION['product'])  != 0){
//  offerte overzicht
$offerte            = "SELECT * FROM `snm_content` WHERE `id` in (".$conn->real_escape_string($prods).")  AND state = 1";
$offertecon         = $conn->query($offerte);
$offertecr          = array();
while ($offertecr[] = $offertecon->fetch_array());
}
```

But now everytime I reload the page, the id is added again, it's not really bad since the products are only loaded once, but still I would like to fix this, because I think a query checking for tons of duplicate ids is not the best way.

Comment: if [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) ...

Comment: @Dave That is exactly what I said in my question, I figured I had to use that, but don't know how to use it.

Comment: How to use `in_array`?

Comment: @u_mulder No how to use it with my variables, but I fixed it. What do you recommend? Answering my own question or deleting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `in_array` is simple - you just check if `element is in array`:

```
var_dump(in_array($element, $array));
```

In your case it is:

```
var_dump(in_array($_GET['product'], $_SESSION['product']));
```

And the check is:

```
// i advise you to check product value as `int`.  
// Because values as `empty string` or `0` or `false` are considered set
if( 0 < intval($_GET['product']) && !in_array($_GET['product'], $_SESSION['product']) ) {
    $_SESSION['product'][] = $_GET['product'];
}
```

But the more clever solution is to use product id as an array key with some fixed value (`1` or `true` for example):

```
$_SESSION['product'] = [
    '101' => 1,
    '102' => 1,
    '106' => 1,
];
```

In this case you don't even need to check if your key exists - if it exists it will be overwritten, if not - will be added:

```
if( 0 < intval($_GET['product']) ) {
    $_SESSION['product'][ $_GET['product'] ] = 1;
}
// but here you need to take array keys instead of values
$prods  = implode(",", array_keys($_SESSION['product']));
```

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**
Use `in_array()` to prevent duplicates:

```
// CHECK FIRST THAT $_GET['product'] IS SET BEFORE ADDING IT TO SESSION
if( isset($_GET['product'])){
    if(!in_array($_GET['product'], $_SESSION['product']){
        // product not exists in array
        $_SESSION['product'][] = $_GET['product'];
    }
}
```

**Option 2** empty array before adding products

```
//if(!isset($_SESSION['product'])){
    $_SESSION['product'] = array();
//}
```